# Django South - Migration not re-creating model after dropping table from sqlite3

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-south

I am a newbie and a new user to Django and South. I created a new model (approval.py) in my models package (and linked it in model's **init**.py) and was able to successfully migrate my app to accept the new model. However, when I tried looking for that model on the admin site, I was getting a 403 forbidden error since the Guardian permissions were not applied. 
So I directly dropped the table from sqlite command prompt and tried to perform the following commands again:

```
   $python manage.py syncdb 
   ...
   (use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)

   $python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
   Nothing seems to have changed.

   $python manage.py migrate myapp
   Running migrations for myapp:
   - Nothing to migrate.
    - Loading initial data for myapp.
   Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

However, the table is no longer getting created, when I check in sqlite command prompt. Also, I had registered this model on my admin.sites.url, but it is no longer displaying it and giving error as:

```
DatabaseError at /admin/myapp/approval/
no such table: myapp_approval
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost/admin/approval/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: DatabaseError
Exception Value:    
no such table: myapp_approval
Exception Location: /home/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 362
Python Executable:  /home/bin/python2.7
Python Version: 2.7.5
Python Path:    
['.........']
Server time:    Wed, 9 Jul 2014 19:12:00 -0500
```

I have already checked all the other questions posted on StackOverflow about using South for migrations, in particular the error about "Nothing seems to have changed". However I am not able to resolve my issue with any of those solutions.

I kindly request some help in either :

- Creating the approval model again from scratch and migrating it successfully
- Or Repairing the existing approval model.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after a lot of trial and error, something very simple worked for me. I did not have much luck with the south migrations. So as I had manually dropped the table from sqlite3, I decided to manually create the table in sqlite3 and everything worked perfectly fine. 
I used the below script on the sqlite3 prompt and it solved my issue and I was able to access the approval page correctly through my admin site and perform all CRUD operations on it.

```
CREATE TABLE "myapp_approval" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "desc" varchar(256) NOT NULL);
```

Thanks everyone for your help and support!

Comment: FWIW I didn't have to go into much detail when re-creating a table. CREATE TABLE "myapp_approval" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) by itself got the table started, then running migrate completed the rest of it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have already created a migration that creates the new table, and according to South's history management, you've run this migration. South does not know about the actual changes to your database.

What you need to do is to revert to a migration before the new table was created. If you look in your apps folder, you'll find a `migrations` folder with some migration files in it. If you created the new table in e.g. migration `0005`, you need to (optionally) migrate backwards to `0005`, and then you need to fake a backwards migration to `0004` and migrate again:

```
manage.py migrate myapp 0005
manage.py migrate myapp 0004 --fake
manage.py migrate myapp
```

Comment: Hi @knbk, unfortunately the backwards migration did not work for me because it did not find the approval table anymore (as I had manually dropped it from sqlite3) . I am getting the following error:

Comment: Running migrations for myapp:
 - Migrating backwards to just after 0002_auto__add_test.
 < myapp:0003_auto__add_approval
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: DROP TABLE "myapp_approval";
The error was: no such table: myapp_approval
 ! Error found during real run of migration! Aborting.

 ! Since you have a database that does not support running
 ! schema-altering statements in transactions, we have had 
 ! to leave it in an interim state between migrations.